# Meta-analysis of linear and non-linear associations: R2 as the "effect size"?

Tags: regression, meta-analysis, nonlinear-regression, r-squared, splines

I have a question regarding meta-analysis of effect sizes of associations.

I was wondering whether it is possible to compare results across studies that modelled the association between two variables "linearly" (e.g. using simple linear regression) vs. others that modelled the association "non-linearly" (e.g. polynomials or splines). One variable is continuous (hormone concentration) and the other is ordinal (self-report of well-being).

For instance, would it be possible to meta-analyze the (adjusted) R2 as the "effect size"? If so, how would one go about the meta-analytic steps?

I figured that meta-analysis of proportions might be applicable, but then I would need the counts on which the proportion is based, which is not directly available for this “proportion”, especially not in the non-linear case.

I started thinking about meta-analyzing "explained variance" in the first place because I cannot summarize the "regression coefficients" across these models; non-linear models include several coefficients, whereas linear analyses only provide one. Then again, R2 is not really applicable as a goodness of fit measure for non-linear models. So which other "summary statistic" to use that is available and comparable for these models, even when comparing them in a non-quantitative way? Would the [Standard Error of the Regression](https://statisticsbyjim.com/regression/standard-error-regression-vs-r-squared/) be an option? But how to standardize it to make it comparable across studies?

I would be very grateful for any ideas or pointers! Thanks in advance!

Comment: The same value of $R^2$ can be obtained from very different models so it is hard to see this working.

Comment: I agree with @mdewey. It is also non-directional. We want an effect size that reflects both the size and direction of the effect (and to be comparable across studies). I'm also not sure why you would want the adjusted R-squared as that then reflects the effect and sample size.